# How to divide the content of an RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an rdd that I will like to divide the content and return a list of tuple.

```
rdd_to_divide = [('Nate', (1.2, 1.2)), ('Mike', (5, 10)), ('Ben', (3, 7)), ('Chad', (12, 20))]

result_rdd = [('Nate', 1.2/1.2), ('Mike', 5/10), ('Ben', 3/7), ('Chad', 12/20)]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda function to map the dataframe as below:

```
>>> rdd_to_divide = sc.parallelize([('Nate', (1.2, 1.2)), ('Mike', (5, 10)), ('Ben', (3, 7)), ('Chad', (12, 20))])

>>> result_rdd = rdd_to_divide.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0]/x[1][1]))
>>> result_rdd.take(5)
[('Nate', 1.0), ('Mike', 0.5), ('Ben', 0.42857142857142855), ('Chad', 0.6)]
```